# Elasticsearch custom categorical sort without scripts

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, groovy

I have a categorical field (let's call it `political_party`) in my documents in ElasticSearch, and I want to implement the following sorting algorithm:

1. If `political_party` is `D` or `R`, put in the first bucket. If it's `G`, they should all go at the end.
2. Within those two buckets, results should be ordered by `date_registered`.

I know that this can be done like this:

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "_script": {
                "script": "doc['political_party'].value == 'G' ? 0 : 1",
                "type": "number",
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "date_registered": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, due to the configuration required to get scripts running and some constraints we have from our hosted ElasticSearch vendor, I need to do this **without** using a `_script` field.  How can this be done?

Comment: You can put your scripts in file. This way you will not have to enable scripting

Answer (score 0):

Since the default sort is done on the `_score` field, you could use a [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to compute a custom score to match your constraints above. No scripting required.

The main idea is to give a weight of 2 to all the documents having `political_party` being `D` or `R` (and leave the default weight of 1 for `G`) and then simply score each document according to its `date_registered` field.

It would go like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "political_party": [
                "D",
                "R"
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "date_registered",
            "factor": 1,
            "modifier": "none"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With this query, all `D` and `R` documents will bubble up to the top and `G` documents will go down. All will be sorted according to their `date_registered` field.

Comment: Thanks.  Issue is I'm actually also calculating `_score` using other things so I'm not sure I can do this; this was a simplified example--but the example helped.

Comment: If you need to compute your own custom score based on other constraints, `function_score` is exactly the way to go, what else is missing for you in this answer?